# How to use pandas to sort data in an excel file. and sort through duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter data using panda.

````
df_c = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\output-mutations.csv')
df_c.drop_duplicates(subset = ["FILENAME", "CHAIN", "MUTATION_CODE"],
                     keep = False, inplace = True)
df_c.to_csv (r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\output-mutations-concise.csv')```
````

Right now, this is all I have. I am trying to remove duplicates in one of my columns, and print all matches in my last column. I have an example of what I'd like to do, but I don't know where to start and what commands to use with panda. I tried the .drop command.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` instead of `drop`.

```
df = df.groupby(by=[ "FILENAME", "CHAIN"],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: ";".join(x["MUTATION_CODE"]))
df.columns = ["FILENAME", "CHAIN", "MUTATION_CODE"]
print(df)
```